# angular.io anchor link menu

Tags: angular, menu, anchor

On angular.io (ex: https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh) and material.angular.io (ex: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview), we can see on the right side of page a nice dynamic menu of page anchors. I wonder how they do that, if it is an existing component, if they use a third-party library, or if it is custom private code. I see there's an ngx-page-scroll library that can help, but maybe there is a more appropriate component for angular or material.angular, maybe using side-nav. This is helpful for page with long content and lots of paragraphs.
[image: anchors side menu]

Answer (score 1):

About first link ([Router tutorial: tour of heroes](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh)) - they used component `aio-toc`. [See Component Ref](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/src/app/custom-elements/toc/toc.component.ts)

For the second link ([Date Picker Overview](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)) - they used component `table-of-contents`. [See Component Ref](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/shared/table-of-contents/table-of-contents.ts)